# How to flatten a collection with Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Scala I can flatten a collection using :

```
val array = Array(List("1,2,3").iterator,List("1,4,5").iterator)
                                                  //> array  : Array[Iterator[String]] = Array(non-empty iterator, non-empty itera
                                                  //| tor)


    array.toList.flatten                      //> res0: List[String] = List(1,2,3, 1,4,5)
```

But how can I perform similar in Spark ?

Reading the API doc http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/api/core/index.html#spark.RDD there does not seem to be a method which provides this functionality ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try flatMap with an identity map function (`y => y`):

```
scala> val x = sc.parallelize(List(List("a"), List("b"), List("c", "d")))
x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala> x.collect()
res0: Array[List[String]] = Array(List(a), List(b), List(c, d))

scala> x.flatMap(y => y)
res3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = FlatMappedRDD[3] at flatMap at <console>:15

scala> x.flatMap(y => y).collect()
res4: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: although this is functionally correct, this solution would not be distributed and will bottleneck at the driver/master. The solution from samthebest is much better.

Comment: @user3746632: the `collect()` calls were just for illustration purposes, to show that, indeed, the results were flattened.

Comment: @JoshRosen, why does it work? y => y (or identity) is mapping the content to itself... is it an implicit thing happening due the fact that "y" is a transversable ?

Answer (score 37):

Use `flatMap` and the `identity` `Predef`, this is more readable than using `x => x`, e.g.

```
myRdd.flatMap(identity)
```

Comment: The `Predef` object provides definitions that are accessible in all Scala compilation units without explicit qualification (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$.html)