# Spark: RDD.saveAsTextFile when using a pair of (K,Collection[V])

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset of employees and their leave-records. Every record (of type **EmployeeRecord**) contains EmpID (of type **String**) and other fields. I read the records from a file and then transform into PairRDDFunctions:

```
val empRecords = sc.textFile(args(0))
....

val empsGroupedByEmpID = this.groupRecordsByEmpID(empRecords)
```

At this point, 'empsGroupedByEmpID' is of type RDD[String,Iterable[EmployeeRecord]]. I transform this into PairRDDFunctions:

```
val empsAsPairRDD = new PairRDDFunctions[String,Iterable[EmployeeRecord]](empsGroupedByEmpID)
```

Then, I go for processing the records as per the logic of the application. Finally, I get an RDD of type [Iterable[EmployeeRecord]]

```
val finalRecords: RDD[Iterable[EmployeeRecord]] = <result of a few computations and transformation>
```

When I try to write the contents of this RDD to a text file using the available API thus:

```
finalRecords.saveAsTextFile("./path/to/save")
```

the I find that in the file every record begins with an ArrayBuffer(...). What I need is a file with one EmployeeRecord in each line. Is that not possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I have spotted the missing API. It is well...flatMap! :-)

By using flatMap with identity, I can get rid of the Iterator and 'unpack' the contents, like so:

```
finalRecords.flatMap(identity).saveAsTextFile("./path/to/file")
```

That solves the problem I have been having.

I also have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138352/how-to-flatten-a-collection-with-spark-scala?rq=1) suggesting the same thing. I wish I saw it a bit earlier.