# Scala Spark - convert RDD[List[scala.Double]] to RDD[scala.Double]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am calling the mllib Statistics.corr() function and receiving the following error:

> (x: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[java.lang.Double],y: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[java.lang.Double],method: String)scala.Double  (x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Double],y: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Double],method: String)scala.Double
>   cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[scala.Double]], org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[scala.Double]], String)
>
> ```
> println(Statistics.corr(a, b, "pearson"))
> ```

What do I need to do to convert my datatype to the proper input type of corr()?

Comment: Please show the types of `a` and `b`. It seems they are `RDD[List[Double]]`, but should be `RDD[Double]`.

Comment: As shown in the error, they are indeed types of RDD[List[Double]]

Comment: As stated in the question, I would like to know how to convert RDD[List[Double]] to RDD[Double]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `flatMap`, with the identity function:

```
val doubleRDD = listDoubleRDD.flatMap(identity)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138352/how-to-flatten-a-collection-with-spark-scala), you want to `flatten` your `RDD`s. Unfortunately, there is no `flatten` method on `RDD`, so you can use `flatMap(identity)`.

```
println(Statistics.corr(a.flatMap(identity), b.flatMap(identity), "pearson"))
```